# Getting index of checkbox and removing them from list instead of iterating entire list

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want know how to get indexes of checkboxes and remove them from list at a time but not by iterating. How to do this? plz someone help me...

Here are my apex class and vf page:

```
public class DeletingCheckedRowsController {
    public List<WrapperClass> listWrapper {get;set;}
    public list<integer> temp{get;set;}
    public Boolean allchecked {get;set;}
    public DeletingCheckedRowsController() {
        listWrapper = new List<WrapperClass>();
        List<contact> contactList = [SELECT Id, firstName, lastname, Email, Phone FROM contact];
        if(contactList.size() > 0) {
            for(contact con : contactList) {
                listWrapper.add(new WrapperClass(con));
            }
        }
    }

    public class WrapperClass {
        public Boolean checked {get;set;}
        public contact con {get;set;}
        public WrapperClass(contact con) {
            this.con = con;
        }
    }

    public void del() {
        integer count=0;
        temp=new list<integer>();
        List<contact> listconForDel = new List<contact>();
        List<WrapperClass> listTempWrapper = new List<WrapperClass>();
        for(WrapperClass w : listWrapper) {
            count++;
            if(w.checked) {
                if(w.con.id==null)
                {
                   temp.add(count-1);
                }
                else
                listconForDel.add(w.con);
            }
            else {
                listTempWrapper.add(w);
            }
        }

        if(temp.size()>0){
            for(integer i=temp.size();i>0;i--)
            {
                listWrapper.remove(temp[i-1]);
            }
        }

        if(listconForDel.size() > 0) {
            delete listconForDel;
            listWrapper = listTempWrapper;
        }
    }

    public void selectAll() {
        if(allchecked) {
            for(WrapperClass w : listWrapper) {
                w.checked = true;
            }
        } else {
            for(WrapperClass w : listWrapper) {
                w.checked = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddRow()
    {
        contact c = new contact();
        listWrapper.add(new WrapperClass(c));
    }

    public void insertnewrows()
    {
        list<contact> conts=new list<contact>();
        for(wrapperclass wrap:listwrapper){
            if(wrap.checked)
            conts.add(wrap.con);
        }
        upsert conts;
    }
}
```

vf page:

```
<apex:page controller="DeletingCheckedRowsController">
<apex:pagemessages />
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock id="pb">
       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listWrapper}" var="w" id="pbt">
           <apex:column > 
               <apex:facet name="header">
                   <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!allchecked}">
                       <apex:actionSupport reRender="pb" action="{!selectAll}" event="onchange"/>
                   </apex:inputCheckbox>
               </apex:facet>
               <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!w.checked}"/>
           </apex:column>
           <apex:column headerValue="Contact First Name">
                <apex:inputfield value="{!w.con.firstName}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Contact Last Name">
                <apex:inputfield value="{!w.con.lastName}"/>
            </apex:column>
           <apex:column headerValue="Contact Email">
                <apex:inputfield value="{!w.con.email}"/>
            </apex:column>
           <apex:column headerValue="Contact Phone Number">
                <apex:inputfield value="{!w.con.phone}"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
        <br/><apex:commandLink value="Add Row" action="{!Addrow}" reRender="pbt"/>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Save Selected rows" action="{!insertnewrows}" reRender="pbt"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Delete Selected" action="{!del}" reRender="pbt"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: N.B. you'll need a where clause as otherwise this will retrieve every Contact in the database. As for the issue at hand, you will need a map of contactIdToWrapperClass in controller and an actionFunction in the page that locates all the checked items and uses assignTo to pass the array of ids to controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice for this type of pattern is actually to ditch your wrapper class entirely, and instead have the page loop over the records directly and use a Map to record the selection state of each record. Doing this, you can bind the apex:inputCheckbox directly to the Map, and can easily remove items by record Id.

As an example, take a look at this `SortableRecordTable` VF component and controller that I made recently. **Note:** due to a [current platform bug](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008bIkAAI), you cannot directly use this component at this time, but it should provide a reasonable example of the pattern.

### Controller

```
public with sharing class SortableRecordTableCtrl {
    private Set<String> nonSortableFields = new Set<String>();
    private FieldSetMember[] tableFields;
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController standardSetController {get; set;}
    public Map<Id,Boolean> selectionMap                          {get; set;}
    public sObjectType tableType                                 {get; set;}
    public String record_query_string                            {get; set;}
    public String objectName                                     {get; set;}
    // Current sort field and direction
    public String sortField                                      {get; set;}
    public boolean sortASC                                       {get { return sortASC == null ? true : sortASC; } set; }

    // Get the list of records for the page you're on
    public List<sObject> CurrentPageRows { 
        get {
            List<sObject> returnList = new List<sObject>();
            for(sObject record : standardSetController.getRecords()){
                if(!selectionMap.containsKey(record.Id)){
                    selectionMap.put(record.Id, false);
                }
                returnList.add(record);
            }
            return returnList;
        }
        set;
    }

    //default constructor
    public SortableRecordTableCtrl(sObjectType objType, String customQuery){
        this.selectionMap = new Map<Id,Boolean>();
        this.tableFields = new List<FieldSetMember>();
        this.tableType = objType;
        this.objectName = tableType.getDescribe().getName();
        this.record_query_string = customQuery;
        finishSetup();
    }
    //better constructor
    public SortableRecordTableCtrl(FieldSet tableFieldSet, Map<Id,Boolean> selections){
        this.tableFields = tableFieldSet.getFields();
        this.tableType = tableFieldSet.getSObjectType();
        //DO NOT make a clone of selection map so that both Ctrls stay synced to the same location in memory
        this.selectionMap = selections;
        this.objectName = tableType.getDescribe().getName();
        Set<String> QueryFields = new Set<String>{'Id', 'Name'};
        QueryFields.addAll(this.FieldsetFieldStrings());
        if(String.isBlank(record_query_string)){
            this.record_query_string = 'SELECT ' + String.join(new List<String>(QueryFields), ',')+' FROM '+objectName+' ORDER BY Name';
        }
        finishSetup();
    }
    private void finishSetup(){
        this.sortField = 'Name';
        this.standardSetController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.Query(record_query_string));
        this.standardSetController.setPageSize(10);
    }

    public List<FieldSetMember> FieldSetList {
        get{
            if(FieldSetList == null){
                FieldSetList = new List<FieldSetMember>();
                Map<String, SObjectField> objFields = CommonDynamicApex.lookupMapSobjectAllFieldsApiNameToFieldToken(this.tableType);

                for(FieldSetMember currentMember : this.tableFields) {
                    SObjectField objField = objFields.get(currentMember.getFieldPath().toLowercase());
                    if(objField != null && objField.getDescribe().isAccessible()) {
                        FieldSetList.add(currentMember);
                        if(!objField.getDescribe().isSortable()){
                            nonSortableFields.add(currentMember.getFieldPath());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return FieldSetList;
        }
        private set;
    }

    private Set<String> FieldsetFieldStrings() {
        Set<String> returnStrings = new Set<String>();
        for(FieldSetMember currentField : this.FieldSetList) {
            returnStrings.add(currentField.getFieldPath());
            if(currentField.getType() == DisplayType.Reference){//also query in the name of referenced record
                String relatedName = currentField.getFieldPath();
                if(relatedName.endsWith('__c')){
                    relatedName = relatedName.substringBeforeLast('__c')+'__r.Name';
                }else{
                    relatedName = relatedName.removeEndIgnoreCase('Id')+'.Name';
                }
                returnStrings.add(relatedName);
            }
        }
        return returnStrings;
    }

    public Integer getNumberRecordsSelected(){
        return retrieveSelectedRecordIdSet().size();
    }

    public Set<ID> retrieveSelectedRecordIdSet() { 
        Set<ID> returnIDs = new Set<ID>();
        for(Id currentItem : selectionMap.keySet()) {
            if(selectionMap.get(currentItem)==true) {
                returnIDs.add(currentItem);
            }
        }
        return returnIDs;
    }

    public List<sObject> retrieveSelectedRecordRows() {
        Set<Id> selectedRows = this.retrieveSelectedRecordIdSet();
        String[] qryBits = record_query_string.split('ORDER BY');
        String qry = qryBits[0]+' WHERE Id IN :selectedRows ORDER BY '+qryBits[1];
        return new List<sObject>(Database.query(qry));
    }

    public Boolean BroadSelection{
        get{
            Boolean broadSelect = true;
            for(sObject record : CurrentPageRows){
                broadSelect &= selectionMap.get(record.Id);
            }
            return broadSelect;
        }
        set;
    }
    public transient Boolean checked    {get; set;}
    public void selectAll(){
        for(sObject record : CurrentPageRows){
            selectionMap.put(record.Id, checked);
        }
    }

    // Sort the collection using the current sortField
    public void sortCollection() {
        if(!nonSortableFields.contains(this.sortField)) {
            String sortingOn = this.sortField;
            try{
                DescribeFieldResult fDesc = this.tableType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(this.sortField).getDescribe();
                if(fDesc.getType() == DisplayType.Reference){
                    if(sortField.endsWith('__c')){
                        sortingOn = sortField.substringBeforeLast('__c')+'__r.Name';
                    }else{
                        sortingOn = sortField.substringBeforeLast('Id')+'.Name';
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                //field path not found in describe
            }
            this.record_query_string = record_query_string.substringBefore('ORDER BY') +'ORDER BY '+sortingOn +' '+(this.sortASC ? 'ASC' : 'DESC');
            Integer currentPageSize = standardSetController.getPageSize();
            standardSetController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.query(this.record_query_string));
            standardSetController.setpageSize(currentPageSize);
            standardSetController.first();
        }else{
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING, 'Selected field cannot be sorted.'));
        }
    } // End sortCollection

}
```

### VF Component

```
<apex:component id="sortableTableComp" access="public" allowDML="false" >
    <apex:attribute name="tableCtrl" type="SortableRecordTableCtrl" description="instance of SortableRecordTableCtrl" required="true"  />
    <apex:attribute name="selectMode" type="Boolean" description="should the table display a column of select boxes?" required="false" default="true" />
    <apex:attribute name="extraRerenders" type="String" description="A $Component expression representing additional areas to rerender when performing table actions. MUST prepend a comma or rerendering will break" required="false" default="" />

    <!-- here's a neat status spinner which also prevents Users from spamming page actions -->
    <apex:actionStatus id="lockScreen">
        <apex:facet name="start">
            <div class="waitingSearchDiv" id="el_loading" style="background-color: #EEE; height: 100%; width:100%; opacity:0.65; z-index: 9998;"/> 
            <div class="waitingSearchDiv" style="height: 100%; width:100%; z-index: 9999; position: fixed;">
                <div class="waitingHolder" style="top: 50%; width: 100px;">
                    <img class="waitingImage" src="/img/loading.gif" title="Please Wait..." style="width: 33px;" />
                    <div class="waitingDescription">Loading...</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </apex:facet>
    </apex:actionStatus>

    <apex:pageBlockSection id="tableSection" columns="1" >
        <!-- table of data --> 
        <apex:pageBlockTable id="theTable" value="{! tableCtrl.CurrentPageRows }" var="recordRow" >
            <apex:column id="selectCol" width="20px" rendered="{!selectMode}">
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:inputCheckbox id="selectAllBox" value="{!tableCtrl.BroadSelection}" title="Select All {!$ObjectType[tableCtrl.objectName].LabelPlural}" >
                        <apex:actionSupport id="selectAll" action="{!tableCtrl.selectAll}" event="onchange" status="lockScreen" reRender="theTable,selectedCount">
                            <apex:param name="checked" value="{!!tableCtrl.BroadSelection}" assignTo="{!tableCtrl.checked}" />
                        </apex:actionSupport>
                    </apex:inputCheckbox>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="selectBox" value="{!tableCtrl.selectionMap[recordRow.Id]}" >
                    <apex:actionSupport id="updateColHeaders" event="onchange" reRender="{!$Component.selectAllBox},selectedCount" />
                </apex:inputCheckbox>
            </apex:column>
            <!-- Fieldset Fields -->
            <apex:repeat id="fieldsRepeat" value="{! tableCtrl.FieldSetList }" var="currentField">
                <apex:column id="dynamicCol" value="{! recordRow[currentField] }">
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:outputLabel id="colHead" style="cursor: {!IF($ObjectType[tableCtrl.objectName].fields[currentField].Sortable, 'pointer', 'default')};" >
                            {! SUBSTITUTE(currentField.Label, ' ID', '') } {! IF(currentField == tableCtrl.sortField, IF(tableCtrl.sortASC, '▲', '▼'), '') }
                            <apex:actionSupport action="{! tableCtrl.sortCollection }" event="onclick" rendered="{!$ObjectType[tableCtrl.objectName].fields[currentField].Sortable}" status="lockScreen" reRender="{!$Component.sortableTableComp.tableSection}{!extraRerenders}">
                                <apex:param value="{! IF(currentField == tableCtrl.sortField, NOT(tableCtrl.sortASC), true) }" assignTo="{! tableCtrl.sortASC }" name="sortASC" />
                                <apex:param value="{! currentField }" assignTo="{! tableCtrl.sortField }" name="sortField" />
                            </apex:actionSupport>
                        </apex:outputLabel>
                    </apex:facet>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:repeat>
            <!-- End Fieldset Fields -->
            <apex:facet name="footer">
                <apex:outputPanel id="paginationContainer" style="justify-content: center; text-align: center;">
                    <!-- count of selected items -->
                    <apex:outputLabel id="selectedCount" style="display: block;" value="[ {! tableCtrl.NumberRecordsSelected} records selected ]" rendered="{!selectMode}" />

                    <!-- next, previous and page info -->
                    <apex:outputPanel id="paginators" layout="block" rendered="{!tableCtrl.standardSetController.ResultSize > 10}">
                        <apex:commandButton id="firstPage" action="{! tableCtrl.standardSetController.first}" status="lockScreen" reRender="{!$Component.sortableTableComp.tableSection}" disabled="{!!tableCtrl.standardSetController.HasPrevious}" value="<< First" />
                        &nbsp;
                        <apex:commandButton id="prevPage" action="{! tableCtrl.standardSetController.previous}" status="lockScreen" reRender="{!$Component.sortableTableComp.tableSection}" disabled="{!!tableCtrl.standardSetController.HasPrevious}" value="< Previous" />
                        <apex:outputLabel id="pageCount" value=" (Page <strong>{! tableCtrl.standardSetController.PageNumber}</strong> of <strong>{!CEILING(tableCtrl.standardSetController.ResultSize/tableCtrl.standardSetController.PageSize)}</strong>) " escape="false" />
                        <apex:commandButton id="nextPage" action="{! tableCtrl.standardSetController.next}" status="lockScreen" reRender="{!$Component.sortableTableComp.tableSection}" disabled="{!!tableCtrl.standardSetController.HasNext}" value="Next >" />
                        &nbsp;
                        <apex:commandButton id="lastPage" action="{! tableCtrl.standardSetController.last}" status="lockScreen" reRender="{!$Component.sortableTableComp.tableSection}" disabled="{!!tableCtrl.standardSetController.HasNext}" value="Last >>" />
                        <br />
                    </apex:outputPanel>

                    <!-- Records per Page -->
                    <apex:outputPanel id="recsPerPage" layout="block" rendered="{!tableCtrl.standardSetController.ResultSize > 10}">
                        <apex:outputLabel value="# of Records per Page" for="NumRecordsToDisplayPerPage"/>&nbsp;
                        <apex:selectList id="NumRecordsToDisplayPerPage" value="{!tableCtrl.standardSetController.PageSize}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!tableCtrl.standardSetController.first}" status="lockScreen" reRender="{!$Component.sortableTableComp.tableSection}"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="10" itemValue="10" />
                            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="25" itemValue="25" />
                            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="50" itemValue="50" />
                            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="100" itemValue="100" />
                            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="200" itemValue="200" />
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:facet>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>


</apex:component>
```

Comment: can I have small piece of code that uses map and checkboxes?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a hefty example :)

Comment: lockscreen component??

Comment: Ahh yes, that's my actionStatus component which provides a status spinner and locks the screen from further User input while page actions are processing. I'll update my answer with the raw version of that component :)